# .NET: How are GUIDs and Random number generated under .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, random, compact-framework, guid

I would like to ask how are random GUIDs and Random numbers generated under .NET Compact Framework? I was under the impression that they are using the clock to generate their randomness, but I did some experiment and it doesn't seem that they are using the clock to generate their randomness. This is the code that i used.

```
Random r = new Random();

string strGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
int intRandom = r.Next();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

I ran them 4 times on our device running .NET compact framework 2.0. (Each test are more than 10 seconds apart). I also did something unthinkable for this experiment: on the last two tests, I removed the connection of the crystal oscillator 32.768KHz on the RTC to freeze the time intentionally and see if it can still generate randomness (I removed the RTC, soldered and placed them on a blank PCB board with jumpers and short wires).  Note: I believe, you will not be able to reproduce this on an emulator or PC side due to the removal of the crystal oscillator on the RTC.

---

**Test 1**

dt    {1/8/2016 10:41:14 AM}    System.DateTime

intRandom 765865814    int

strGuid    "63c6117b-9529-427f-822c-1ebc51089b5b" string

**Test 2**

dt    {1/8/2016 10:47:19 AM}    System.DateTime

intRandom    203285329    int

strGuid    "2f84ca06-497d-4457-9def-1cf59abb4ca0"    string

**Test 3**

dt    {1/8/2016 10:47:52 AM}    System.DateTime

intRandom    1935598076    int

strGuid    "5ea1fe9e-0059-4bdb-b3ad-e1197e4b8d9e"    string

**Test 4**

dt    {1/8/2016 10:47:52 AM}    System.DateTime

intRandom    1481224450    int

strGuid    "4123b229-998c-4aeb-b90c-dd64db145b23"    string

---

On test 1, the crystal oscillator is still connected. So far everything is ok.

On test 2, the crystal oscillator is still connected. The datetime is moving. So far, everything ok. After this test, the crystal oscillator's connection was removed. So far everything is ok.

On test 3, the crystal oscillator is disconnected before starting the test. So far everything is ok but do take note of the time.

On test 4, as expected, the timestamp is the same with test 3 due to the removal of the connection to the crystal oscillator. But the GUIDs and Random number generated are still random.

I repeated this experiment for 3 times already to ensure that I did nothing wrong. With this, how could it be that the GUIDs and the Random number are still random, despite the stoppage of the clock?

Comment: Might I suggest it may have been simpler to read the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,b7fae6994c22c22e,references) ([C++ implementation](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2597248/) rather than to physically disconnect a component in your PC?

Comment: I would imagine that a seed may have already been generated before the crystal was removed, so the randomness is still working. Does it still happen after rebooting (if it will even reboot?)

Comment: Hi Rob, just now I rebooted the device and did 5 tests with the crystal oscillator removed.

--

dt {1/8/2016 10:49:12 AM}

intRandom 467443139

strGuid "f23e91f0-8186-4076-8f1d-066c8db46af9"

--



dt {1/8/2016 10:49:12 AM}

intRandom 1401299602

strGuid "a590addd-2879-4803-b256-a24b02aea259"

--

dt {1/8/2016 10:49:12 AM}

intRandom 1567367520

strGuid "dc938ca6-213f-4a45-bda5-62676751e044"

--


dt {1/8/2016 10:49:12 AM}

intRandom 130509578

strGuid "0ff7376b-4f1c-465c-926a-414c426c4358"

--


dt {1/8/2016 10:49:12 AM}

intRandom 1465038237

strGuid "5645dbe5-7eaa-41a2-9b84-c1453cbc605f"

Comment: Rob, thanks for the source code though (I didnt know that the code is open for public to see). I will read it. :)

Comment: On further examination, it appears the `CoCreateGuid` may not be the one used by .NET - I can't find a source on that, though I would imagine they are very much similar. I can only guess that seeds have been cached  , since the random number is also changing.

Comment: hi Rob, I think that is correct. As I had been looking on the CoCreateGuid source code. Since the clock is not moving, it seems to me that it enters on the if statement at line 182 and it doesn't reset the static int count, instead it is incremented and then used that value to generate the GUIDs. Thank you for that. I think my query has been answered. :)

Comment: what's ur purpose? are u trying to find out something to address a problem? is the Guid is not generating unique value?

Comment: Hi Kelmen, yes I am trying to address a problem. Initially we have a list of IDs, and this uses time stamp (date and time up to seconds). But then, our customers noticed that the IDs are the same and I found out that there are some issues on hardware which in turn produced duplicated time stamps. And their softwares do check this IDs because it can come from other devices as well. This experiment proved that the time can indeed freeze. Then, we thought of appending a GUID at the end of the current ID to reduce the probability of having duplicated IDs. [To be continued on next post]

Comment: Then, from what I remember, random generators do use clock as a seed, but since we are having problems with the clock, I posted the question so that I will know if there will be some implications on my workaround.  But a good discovery on my side is that the GUID is working even in the absence of a working clock, learned something new today. :)

Comment: @newbieprogrammerz Out of curiosity, does `Environment.TickCount` change? As for your current problem, I'd be careful about using `Guid`s without a clock, unless you test it for millions of guids over a decent amount of time (days?). It's likely solvable by seeding `Random` with a human-entered seed at startup, and appending the random number, or using an online service to give you a 'truly random' seed.

Comment: Hi Rob, your question sparked my curiosity as well. I did try 5 times without the crystal oscillator,  the Environment TickCount **does change and increment**. Although the time, doesn't move.   It looks like I need to recheck my earlier assumptions.

Comment: Environment.TickCount *must* change.  It's hooked to the processor oscillator, not the RTC.  If it isn't running, the processor won't be executing statements.